# Is this file encrypted or what

Tags: encryption

I'm a newbie so I think i need your help. I've found a file on my Ubuntu VPS and when I type cat ss (ss is the name of the file) it shows me

```
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY.
```

I tried oppening it on Windows using Sublime Text 3 and it shows me

```
7f45 4c46 0101 0103 0000 0000 0000 0000
0200 0300 0100 0000 50af c300 3400 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 3400 2000 0200 2800
0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0010 c000
0010 c000 5ca7 0300 5ca7 0300 0500 0000
0010 0000 0100 0000 c80c 0000 c8fc 0c08
c8fc 0c08 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000
0010 0000 04b0 cce2 5550 5821 0b08 0d0c
0000 0000 d097 0800 d097 0800 9400 0000
6100 0000 0800 0000 771f a4f9 7f45 4c46
0100 0200 0300 1be0 8004 fbaf bddf 0834
0ed8 9408 2f16 2032 2800 1300 1200 5b5d
67bb 1b46 07d8 160c 0705 2710 b6ed feb2
007f 1ee0 a60c 0807 5823 1ee8 5506 d79d
7bb7 063f 040c 9407 7607 2016 2449 70d9
```

And so on..

Also I can execute the file with ./ and I think it's a scanner or something. Also I don't want to delete it. I want to see the code inside it.

Comment: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard Putty behavior when you attempt to cat a binary file.

Please see [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-puttyputty) for detailed explanation, the quote from FAQ:

> When PuTTY receives the character Control-E from the remote server, it
>   interprets it as a request to identify itself, and so it sends back
>   the string ‘PuTTY’

ss file is a linux utility to dump socket statistics, you can find more details about it [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/ss.8.html)

If you need source code of this tool then a version of it can be found [here](https://github.com/sivasankariit/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c)

Comment: Ok, it is not a standard ss tool for socket statistics, it is a port scanner (like nmap). I haven´t encountered this particular tool before

Comment: If it is just a single binary file then unfortunately no. The only thing you can try is to decompile or reverse engineer it but it takes a lot of effort and expertise.